# 'Form1.myAxMap' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#

Kind of stuck here.
I am having the error message 'Form1.myAxMap' is inaccessible due to its protection level when I build my program.

here's the problem

```
frm1object.myAxMap.AddLayerFromFilename(outputshapefile, tkFileOpenStrategy.fosVectorLayer, true);
```

Code for Form2.cs

```
namespace Buffer
{
    public partial class frmbuffer : Form
    {
        Form1 frm1object;
        public frmbuffer(Form1 frm1loaded)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            frm1object = frm1loaded;
        }

        private void Btnok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string inputshapefile = inputshp.Text;
            double inputdistance = Convert.ToDouble(distance.Text);
            int inputsegment = Convert.ToInt16(segments.Text);
            bool inputselected = Convert.ToBoolean(selectedonly.Text);
            bool inputmerge = Convert.ToBoolean(mergeresults.Text);
            string outputshapefile = outputshp.Text;
            bool inputoverwrite = Convert.ToBoolean(checkboxoverwrite.Checked);

            Shapefile sf = new Shapefile();
            sf.Open(inputshapefile);

            var utils = new Utils();

            bool bufferprocess = utils.BufferByDistance(sf, inputdistance, inputsegment,
                inputselected, inputmerge,
                outputshapefile, inputoverwrite);


            if (bufferprocess == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Completed", "Report",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                frm1object.myAxMap.AddLayerFromFilename(outputshapefile,tkFileOpenStrategy.fosVectorLayer, true);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed", "Report",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

what should i do?
This is my first time so please help:(

Comment: Please post your `Form1.cs`.

Comment: Change the modifier of `myAxMap` to `public` or `internal`.